# Okvideo : Redirect to another page/section after video finished playing

Tags: jquery, html, video

I was trying to do a full screen background video from vimeo.
So I found okfocus's okvideo, how do I make the page jump to another page after the video finished playing? I'm quite new to jquery~ Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 257 of okvideo.js. It contains a conditional that tests to see if the video is finished. If you replace the next line with something like:

```
location.href = 'http://url.com';
```

this should link to another page once the video is complete. You may have to try setting the onFinsihed option to loop.

Hope that helps!